# How does the Dream Chaser manned differ from Dream Chaser cargo?

Tags: uncrewed-spaceflight

The CRS (Cargo Resupply Services) 2 contract was announced with three winners, SpaceX for Dragon, Orbital for Cygnus, and SNC for Dream Chaser.

How will the cargo version of Dream Chaser differ from proposed manned version?

Answer (score 1):

The information I have been able to find so far is below:

- Folding wings, so it can launch inside a fairing.
- External cargo unit at the rear

Please edit in more info if you find it.

edit: added image from [here](http://www.sncspace.com/Mediakit/Images) showing external cargo.

[image]

Comment: are they going to land it with external cargo ?

Comment: My comment from long ago was wrong, there is an awkward-looking external cargo module attached at the rear, at least according to this image from their website.

Comment: @Zgr3doo the website with images that I linked in the edited answer shows the external cargo module being jettisoned before entry.